# How to enable terminus command in linux (Windows)

Tags: linux, bash, drupal, drush, pantheon

I'm trying to use terminus for my pantheon Drupal site operations. which is in dev stage. I installed terminus in my local system with the help of bash on Ubuntu on windows10. but after installation, I got the message like this....

**Terminus was installed, but the installer was not able to write to your bin dir. To enable the
`terminus` command, add this alias to your .bash_profile (Mac) or .bashrc (Linux) file:
 alias terminus=/home/usr/vendor/bin/terminus
Or you can enable it by adding the directory the executable file is in to your path:
 PATH="/home/usr/vendor/bin:$PATH"**

Thanks anyway

Comment: This Q is not about programming as defined for StackOverflow. It **may** be more appropriate on the S.E. related sites http://superuser.com OR http://unix.stackexchange.com (Unix & Linux). Use the `flag` link at the bottom of your Q and ask the moderator to move it. Please don't post the same Q on 2 different sites. Please read  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you didn't installed terminus as root, so it was installed in your HOME directory.

The message is pretty clear giving you options to work around this issue.

1. Add Terminus to your `.bashrc` as alias.
2. Add the Terminus bin directory to your `$PATH` variable.

I recommend you to use the option #2. If you don't know how to do it, try the command:
`echo 'PATH=${PATH}:/home/usr/vendor/bin' >> "${HOME}/.bashrc"`

I'm assuming the Terminus bin directory is `/home/usr/vendor/bin`. Make sure to use the correct path.